# MYSQL SELECT BY GROUP

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in which I need to query 9 returns, each of which need to be of a random order each time, they cannot duplicate except for one value of TYPE X. The problem is that if using GROUP BY, it only returns 8 results, but I require 9, with 2 results having the same TYPE value.

The draft query I have been using so far has been:
"SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM questions ORDER BY RAND() ) R GROUP BY type;

// TABLE REMOVED, FORMATTING NOT WORKING, IMAGE INSTEAD

[image: MySQL Table]

Comment: Your question doesn't quite make sense.  What is "X"?  What can't be duplicated?

Comment: If you only have 8 distinct `critical_thinking_id` values, then you can't have 9 distinct values.

Comment: Formatting works fine for millions of other questions. Your image is totally useless.

Comment: I only want 9 values showing at a time, all with different critical thinking types, except for 2, and those 2 must have a different id

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch random rows from groups in MySQL, I think the safest way is to use variables.  This is the ordering:

```
select q.*
from (select q.*,
             (@rn := if(@q = questionid, @rn + 1,
                        if(@q := questionid, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from questions q cross join
           (select @q := 0, @rn := 0) params
      order by questionid, rand()
     ) q
```

Then, if you know you have 8 questions but you want 2 from the second:

```
where rn = 1 or (questionid = 2 and rn = 2)
```

Or, if you want 9 random questions as non-overlapping as possible:

```
order by rn
limit 9
```

Comment: Im not sure how the WHERE clause comes into it as the q is returning an error.

Comment: @Nnaut . . . That should be `questionid`.

Comment: The columns in my table are : ID, Question, Critical_Thinking_ID, so what do you mean by questionid

Comment: @Nnaut . . . Your question is entirely vague on what your data looks like.  You should be able to figure out which columns in this answer correspond to which columns in your data.